# Why is the client not receiving server's reply?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

Here is the client class,it takes input from user (word and definition) and the client sends the choice number (in this case the choice number is 1 which represents adding a word) + input to the server.

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    welcomeMessage();
    int choice=input();

    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    Socket clientSocket=new Socket("localhost",8888);
    DataOutputStream toServer=new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));


    String word;
    switch (choice) {

    case 1:
        System.out.println("Adding words\nEnter a word");
         word = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter definition");
        String definition = " ";


            definition += scan.nextLine();

        toServer.writeBytes(choice+";"+word+";"+definition+"\n");
        String str=inFromServer.readLine();

        System.out.println(str);
        break;
            //other cases
    }
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

And here is the server class.

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
        String clientData;
        String[] arr = new String[2];
        Vector<String[]> dictionary = new Vector<String[]>();
        System.out.println("hi");
        while (true) {


            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(   
                    new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(
                    connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientData = inFromClient.readLine();

            int index;
            int in=0;
            switch (clientData.charAt(0)) {
            case '1':   
                connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("I'm in");

                if(dictionary.size()==0 || Bsearch(dictionary,getWord(clientData.substring(2)),0,dictionary.size())==-1){

                arr[0]=getWord(clientData.substring(2));
                arr[1]=getDefinition(clientData.substring(2));
                dictionary.add(in++,arr);

                outToClient.writeBytes("Added successfully");


                }
                else
                outToClient.writeBytes("Word already exists");
                welcomeSocket.close();
                break;
        }

    }
```

The client class is successfully sending to the server but the server isn't sending back.

I think there's some kind of infinite loop in the server because the code of the client doesn't proceed, it keeps on waiting.

Comment: I suggest you debug it. These designs where there are two sockets per client can't ever really work reliably. What happens when two different clients connect more or less simultaneously?

Comment: The server isn't sending a line. Add a line terminator to the message.